# PHP Contact Form Error (loads php file in browser)

Tags: php, html, contacts, contact-form

I am trying to get this contact form for a solar company's website that i am building to work and right now every time I click to submit the form it just opens the php file in the browser. I would really appreciate some help with this bug. Thank you so much in advance!

```html
<!-- BEGIN FORM -->
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header"><!-- modal header -->
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Get Started with SunTegra</h4>
        </div><!-- /modal header -->

        <!-- modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!--FORM-->
          <form action="contactEasy.php" method="post"> 
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label>Choose all that apply</label>
                </div>
                <font size="2">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="homeowner" value="homeowner" class="form-control input-lg"> Homeowner
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="businessowner" value="businessowner" class="form-control input-lg"> Business Owner
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="installer" value="installer" class="form-control input-lg"> Solar Installer
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="distributor" value="distributor" class="form-control input-lg"> Solar Distributor
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="general" value="general" class="form-control input-lg"> General Interest
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="builder" value="builder" class="form-control input-lg"> Green Builder
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="architect" value="architect" class="form-control input-lg"> Architect
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="contractor" value="contractor" class="form-control input-lg"> Roof Contractor
                  </div>
                </font>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label>Name *</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" required="required" class="form-control input-lg ">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label>Email *</label>
                  <input type="text" name="email" required="required" class="form-control input-lg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label>Phone Number *</label>
                  <input type="text" name="number" required="required" class="form-control input-lg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label>Company </label>
                  <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control input-lg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label>Mailing Address *</label>
                  <input type="text" name="address" required="required" class="form-control input-lg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>City *</label>
                  <input type="text" name="city" required="required" class="form-control input-lg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>State *</label>
                  <input type="text" name="state" required="required" class="form-control input-lg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>Zip Code *</label>
                  <input type="text" name="zip" required="required" class="form-control input-lg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label>What is your average monthly electricity bill?</label>
                  <select name="energybill">
                    <option value=""> -- Please select -- </option>
                    <option>Less than $100</option>
                    <option>$101 to $150</option>
                    <option>$151 to $200</option>
                    <option>$251 to $300</option>
                    <option>Greater than $300</option>
                    <option>I don't know</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label>Message *</label>
                  <textarea name="message" rows="3" class="form-control input-lg"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div align="center">
            <button value="send" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg radius6">Discover Solar Now</button></div>

        </div>
        <!-- /modal body -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- END FORM -->


  <!-- PHP FILE (it is on seperate file but this noob couldn't figure out how to implement it on this questionaire -->

  <?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "spereless@gmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$homeowner   = check_input($_POST['homeowner']);
$businessowner   = check_input($_POST['businessowner']);
$installer   = check_input($_POST['installer']);
$distributor   = check_input($_POST['distributor']);
$general   = check_input($_POST['general']);
$builder   = check_input($_POST['builder']);
$architect   = check_input($_POST['architect']);
$contractor   = check_input($_POST['contractor']);

$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$email  = check_input($_POST['email'], "Write a subject");
$company    = check_input($_POST['company']);
$address  = check_input($_POST['address']);
$city = check_input($_POST['city'], "Enter your name");
$state  = check_input($_POST['state'], "Write a subject");
$zip    = check_input($_POST['zip']);

$energybill  = check_input($_POST['energybill']);

$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Write your comments");


/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
$website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

homeowner: $homeowner
businessowner: $businessowner
installer: $installer
distributor: $distributor
general: $general
builder: $builder
architect: $architect
contractor: $contractor

Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Company: $company
Address: $address
City: $city
State: $state
Zip: $zip

Avergae Monthly Bill: $energybill

Comments:
$message

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: index.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
  <html>
    <body>

      <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
      <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
  </html>
  <?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: "contact.php" file opens in browser?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, let me elaborate... My browser window that is showing the website changes from the html page to the php code when i press the submit button...

Comment: is extension of your file is `*.php` , is your `LAMP` on